# php code inside <option> tag

Tags: php

How can I embed php code inside of HTML option tag.

Currently my code runs as following:

```
    $last_y = date("Y") -1;
    echo "<option value='Annual'>Annual - $last_y</option>";
```

But I would like to get rid of the $last_y variable and use "date("Y") -1" inside the option tag.
Have tried different escaping, but this didn't work.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/BS14t

Comment: Result `Annual - 2015` worked fine for me. HTML source `<option value='Annual'>Annual - 2015</option>` - Unless I'm not grasping the question.

Comment: @Ekin The guy's not going to bother replying to you, or any other comments left here.

Comment: *"Have tried different escaping, but this didn't work."* - You should have shown us what you did try, that way your question would have been much clearer. *Just saying* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, will do so. New to stackoverflow, new to php :)

Comment: @Sergio You're welcome, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job :

```
    <?php echo "<option value='Annual'>Annual - ".(date("Y") -1)."</option>"; ?>
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks!
Could you please explain why the dots did the job?

Comment: @Sergio `echo "<option value='Annual'>Annual - $last_y</option>";` and `echo "<option value='Annual'>Annual - ".(date("Y") -1)."</option>";` both produced the same result. I have no idea what your real code looks like.

Comment: Fred, they do. All I wanted is to get rid of the $last_y variable and insert the year calculation inside the option tags. that's all. Code in my question worked, but i didn't like that unnecessary variable and embed the year calculation inside.

Comment: @Sergio I understand. Ok, well... you know that variables do most of the work when they're already pre-defined and you'd only be limiting your code for that single instance. If you were to later want and print it using the old variable you were using, you would be back to square one, *just saying*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
<?php 
 //code
$last_y = date("Y") -1; ?>
<option value='Annual'>Annual - <?php echo $last_y;?> </option>
```

or

```
<?php echo "<option value='Annual'>Annual - ".$last_y."</option>"; ?>
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for comment, but this won't work as the echo is inside <?php>...?>

Comment: @Sergio It will work, `echo` must be in `php` tags to work

Comment: Sorry, replied to the 1st option - my echo is already in php tags.
Second option works as I wanted.
Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio Yes, you can close the `php` tag, write normal HTML code and reopen the tag, I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @Sergio *"Second option works as I wanted"* - `echo "<option value='Annual'>Annual - ".$last_y."</option>";` not by my testing it doesn't.

Comment: The way I wanted it to look like is provided by @maximilienAndile

Comment: @Sergio Sorry, but I find it rather hard to believe in testing with what you posted for code, rather then having to shown us your full/real code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $last_y = date("Y") -1; ?>
<option value='Annual'>Annual - <?php echo $last_y; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the PHP code inside your string you can use [`printf()`](https://php.net/printf) like so

```
printf('<option value="Annual">Annual - %u</option>', date('Y') - 1);
```

This comes in especially handy when you want to use the same value multiple times

```
printf('<option value="Annual %1$u">Annual - %1$u</option>', date('Y') - 1);
```